# Looking replicate static HTML Menu into WordPress Dynamic Menu

Tags: customization, menus, sub-menu

We are converting our static HTML site to Wordpress. The conversion is going fine (for the most part) but the part I cannot figure out is how to build the menu so that I can retain the menu look from our HTML site (see graphic for the specific menu I'm referring too).

Original Site: http://humanetomorrow.org/
[image]

I know how to create the menu in WordPress admin dashboard and have it show up on the page, I guess my question may be more of how to style it with the logo and the "twist" which I could use some pointers on.

UPDATE:
After adding the code provided by the Accepted Answer, I now see non menu item pages appearing on the menu even though they were not added to the menu.
[image: Unwanted Menu Item]

The Info for sponsors page is "just a page" that is linked to within another page, not the menu.

And then my WP Code:

```
            <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'theme_location' => 'primary',
                'container' => 'nav',
                'container_class' => '',
                'menu_class' => 'nav',
                'before' => '',                                         // before the menu
                'after' => '',                                          // after the menu
                'link_before' => '',                                    // before each link
                'link_after' => '',                                     // after each link
                'depth' => 2,
            ) );
        ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Lookup `wp_nav_menu`

Simply take the HTML you have now and remove the `<ul>` or whatever elements you are using to list the menu links. If you want it to be dynamic, your theme template will need something similar to the following placed where you want the links to load in place of what you had in your regular HTML site:

```php
<?php wp_nav_menu(array(
         'container' => false,                           // remove nav container
         'container_class' => 'menu cf',                 // class of container (should you choose to use it)
         'menu' => __( 'The Main Menu', 'mytheme' ),  // nav name
         'menu_class' => 'nav top-nav cf',               // adding custom nav class
         'theme_location' => 'main-nav',                 // where it's located in the theme
         'before' => '',                                 // before the menu
           'after' => '',                                  // after the menu
           'link_before' => '',                            // before each link
           'link_after' => '',                             // after each link
           'depth' => 0,                                   // limit the depth of the nav
         'fallback_cb' => ''                             // fallback function (if there is one)
)); ?>
```

You will also have to register your menu (or menus if you do multiple)

```php
register_nav_menus(
    array(
        'main-nav' => __( 'The Main Menu', 'mytheme' ),   // main nav in header
        'footer-links' => __( 'Footer Links', 'mytheme' ) // secondary nav in footer
    )
);
```

The base theme I use to build WordPress themes has a separate file where you register the menus and image sizes etc.. Not sure if it would work in functions.php or not as I've never tried, but I assume it would. Maybe someone else can chime in to answer that.

The way WordPress creates the navigation should work ok for what you need. Sometimes I hard-code menus when I can't use the WordPress menu HTML setup. Here is an example of a hard-coded menu, which you could turn into a simplified function if you wanted. The php code is just checking the URL basename to see what page we're currently on and add a class to that `<li>` so that the `<li>` and `<a>` tags can be easily styled.

```
<nav>
    <ul>
<?php if(basename(get_the_permalink())=='about') { echo '<li class="current-menu-item"><a class="icon-about">'; } else echo '<li><a class="icon-about" href="/blog/">';?>About</a></li>
<?php if(basename(get_the_permalink())=='services') { echo '<li class="current-menu-item"><a class="icon-service">'; } else echo '<li><a class="icon-service" href="/services/">';?>Services</a></li>
<?php if(basename(get_the_permalink())=='contact') { echo '<li class="current-menu-item"><a class="icon-contact">'; } else echo '<li><a class="icon-contact2" href="/social/">';?>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Hope that helps point you in the right direction.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. That's the hardest part of WordPress is discovering the functions and the syntax and in this case the function `wp_nav_menu` was the missing link.

Comment: By the way, once you get this working, you just need to add the pages or links to the Main Menu by going to the WordPress Admin, in the sidebar on the left of the browser go to Appearance > Menus. Good luck!

Comment: Perhaps I implemented it incorrectly but how do I get "subpages" to not appear on teh menu automatically? Under Appearance > Menus | Menu Settings, the checkbox ofr "Automatically add new top-level pages to this menu" is UNchecked but this setting doesn't appear to be honored correctly. I tried checking it, saving and then unchecking it but that didn't resolve it. Currently the only way I can keep a page from appearing in the menu is to leave it as draft. Once published, it appears. :/

Comment: "sub page" may not be the right term here. For example Adopt is a page at the root level of the site and I want it there. I have another page that is just about an upcoming yearly event (called Fido Fest 2021). I don't need it linked in the menu as there will be a link with in the text of Fido Fest to the Fido Fest 2021 registration but Fido Fest 2021 is appearing at the same level as Adopt, Help, Donate, etc.

Comment: Also, the page has "Main Page (no parent) listed for it's Parent.

Comment: ^--- that was under quick edit. If I do a full edit, the Page Attributes show Parent (no parent) and the Order of 0. I'm stumped.

Comment: You need to use CSS to control the menus. Maybe your theme CSS is not hiding the child pages before you hover the links? Even if that checkbox is unchecked, you need to abide by what the menu looks like on the screen in the admin UI. Make sure "subpages" are nested under the main links. Click drag them to the right a bit and you'll see them shift. You can also try switching to one of the WP base themes and back to your theme to see if that helps.

Comment: I added some screen shots to my original post to help illustrate what I'm referring too. You still think that's a CSS issue? I _feel_ like WP is not honoring the Menu Settings correctly.

Comment: "Info for sponsors and vendors..." Where is that coming from? Maybe your theme is loading in the Tagline from General Settings?

Comment: It's just a basic wordpress page. NO IDEA why it's on the menu.

Comment: Check your template file. Some code is loading it most likely.

Answer (score 0):

that header style is just a background image, rather than an actual css style.

you could apply the image again to the new site's header as a background image - or draw it via css which would require strong technique id imagine.

also the logo, is a separate png image on top of the fancy background image.

take a look at 'css tricks'.

Comment: The logo itself is clickable to allow the user to go back to the homepage. Otherwise, your suggestion would have been spot-on, sir!

Comment: do you want to build the actual image with css? as it stands the logo is a separate image, and it is clickable. that doesn't change that the background image is also an image.

Comment: You are correct, the current image is a separate image. Maybe I misunderstood your answer.